# Use strict mode on Progress bar

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, use-strict

Progress bar is working If I put it directly in the index.html page. But it isn't working (animation) if I put it in external active.js file with "use strict" mode. But Other JS is working fine. Please Help me. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code below:

```
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                trigger: 'manual'
            }).tooltip('show');


        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) { // scroll down abit and get the action   
                $(".progress-bar").each(function() {
                    each_bar_width = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
                    $(this).width(each_bar_width + '%');
                });

            }
        });
```

```
Details code here: https://codepen.io/valencia123/pen/aOopQx
```

Comment: What's not working exactly? And can you provide more code such as the progressbar inside your index.html?

Comment: Animation isn't working. Here is the details code https://codepen.io/valencia123/pen/aOopQx

Comment: It looks like it works fine to me in the codepen, but that may be codepen's fault. Try adding "var" to before each_bar_width and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks man! It works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 'use strict' mode you have to declare every used variable first. From your snippet it's not obvious that `each_bar_width` is being declared anywhere. Try with var or const declaration.